# how to place the contents of a file in a listView? in (android)

Tags: android

I'm making an app about to-do notes 
the user will write his note then pick the time and date he wants this note to ring on . 
I don't know how to save the time and date that he wanna choose with the note he will write 
and how to place all of these notes + their times in a schedule so that when he clicks on "Edit" Button the table appears to him and he picks one of the note to change it .

I wanted to make a file and save the notes inside it but I  failed to save the time of each note accordingly

and I thought of filling a listView with the contents of the file but I had no idea how to do so .

thanks in advance.

Comment: Way too broad to answer. Try using database for storing notes and its time. Don't use file

Comment: Please read about the following subject:
1. sqllite 2. alarmmanager 3. notifications 4. custom listview / recyclerview this should get you started :-)

Comment: You dont want to manage lots of files... please write all the data on the phone using sqllite!

Comment: I know all of these but a friend told me file is easier for you.

Comment: In the layout should I put "time picker" and "date picker" to let him choose from ?
or should i just put a plain texts for the date and time ? 
I'm talking about saving the date and time that he will choose for each note he will write

Comment: A database table is your best friend.